# timeout command not timing out

Tags: bash, timeout, sox

I have some issues with timing out a long-running sox recording.

The command is needed because sox gets stdout from a process, but it's not a permanently flow of data (but has interruptions with silence). But as sox is told to record 30s in total, it records until the audio file has 30s of sound. So I want the command to timeout after 35s if it's not finished before.

Used command in bash script:

timeout 35s sox [--some --sox --parameters] trim 0 30

Now the problem is that the given command may take anything between 35s and >10min and I have no idea why.

It seems completely random how long it takes, and audio files are something between 1s and 13s.

So maybe someone here has an idea, probably how to troubleshoot etc

Comment: I'd prepend `strace -tfesignal` to the `timeout` command and look at the output - this might reveal why `sox` doesn't timely react to SIGTERM.

Comment: To cite a few lines of the log output (command begins at 10s of minute, should timeout at 45s of the minute):
`kill(29944, SIGTERM) = 0
[...]
sigreturn() (mask [] <unfinished ...>
<... kill resumed> ) = 0
[...]
kill(29944, SIGCONT) = 0
[...]
[pid 29944] 15:28:45 sigreturn() (mask []) = 5
[pid 29944] 15:31:54 +++ exited with 0 +++
15:31:54 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=29944, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=88, si_stime=4} ---
15:31:54 +++ exited with 124 +++`
But I can't recognize an actual problem/solution out of the log

Comment: Hm - PID 29944 must be `sox`; we see at the start of the shown output that the terminate signal is successfully sent to it, but at `15:28:45` there's only a `sigreturn()` - it seems `sox` has installed a handler for SIGTERM which prevents the termination; only more than 3 minutes later at `15:31:54` it chooses to exit. You could send SIGKILL instead, which would terminate `sox`, but then necessary cleanup may be missing and the audio output inconsistent. Anyway, the failure to timely react to SIGTERM looks like a deficiency in `sox` which would have to be corrected therein.

Comment: What does `sox` print at the end: `Aborted.`, `Skipped.` or `Done.`?

Comment: Nothing, or at least nothing I would recognize. The last lines of the strace are:

`[pid 29944] 15:28:45 --- SIGCONT {si_signo=SIGCONT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=29943, si_uid=0} ---

[pid 29943] 15:28:45 <... sigreturn resumed> ) = 29944

[pid 29944] 15:28:45 sigreturn() (mask []) = 5

[pid 29944] 15:31:54 +++ exited with 0 +++

15:31:54 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=29944, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=88, si_stime=4} ---

15:31:54 +++ exited with 124 +++`

And yes, 29944 is the PID of sox. Sorry, forgot to add

Comment: No problem! - So, the delay of some minutes is what `sox` means by [_Stop gracefully, as soon as we possibly can._](https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/code/ci/master/tree/src/sox.c#l1771)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [terminate signal handler](https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/code/ci/master/tree/src/sox.c#l1536) in `sox` just sets the flag `user_abort`, which is checked by the [Callback for monitoring flow progress](https://github.com/dmkrepo/libsox/blob/master/src/sox.h#L2146) *once per buffer*, so `sox` waiting until a buffer gets full can explain the long delay for honoring the signal. The situation might improve if you specify a small buffer size, but that's not a solution.

I now noticed that you wrote *sox gets stdout from a process*. If you `timeout` that process rather than `sox`, the closing of its input source should cause `sox` to instantly terminate.

> Unfortunately that's not a suitable solution as the "main process" (sox gets the stdout from) runs 24/7 and shouldn't be interrupted.

You could instead connect `cat` to the input and then `timeout 35 cat | sox …`.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a suitable solution as the "main process" (sox gets the stdout from) runs 24/7 and shouldn't be interrupted.

I also tried just echoing some stuff into the PID by another command (in case sox still runs after 40s) as I thought of something similar like that buffer stuff, but though it's quite dirty, it didn't work as expected...

Comment: How do you connect `sox` to the stdout of an already running "main process"?

Comment: In a bash script I get the PID of the main process and sox connects to /proc/$pid/fd/1 as input file.

Yep, probably not thaaat nice, but it works quite good except for the mentioned problem.

Comment: I still don't grasp how you manage that _sox connects to /proc/$pid/fd/1 as input file_ - surely this doesn't work if that points to a TTY or an ordinary file, does it? But since this works somehow, could you instead connect e. g. `cat` to the input? Then you could `timeout 35 cat | sox …`.

Comment: Yeah well, that was too easy to be honest. Using cat | sox now solved the problem.
And it looks like the audio file also has an actual EOF, though being interrupted by the timeout.

So would you like to repost your comment as a response so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: I did as you suggested, though it remains a riddle to me what kind this _input file_ is you connect to (if I were forced to guess, I'd say a named pipe). :-)

Comment: ls states "/proc/871/fd/1 -> pipe:[782958]" where $pid=871. I have to admit that I don't know exactly what that is, but some time ago I figured out (somehow) it's the stdout of the required process.

Comment: One never finishes learning. I could have sworn that it's not possible to connect to (and seemlessly disconnect from) an ordinary pipe in this way, but it works - thanks for the enlightenment!